# Selenium Auth0 can't connect to server

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, angular, protractor, auth0

I have a protractor selenium test for an angular2 that I run with `protractor conf.js --params.login.username=John --params.login.password=Doe`. The test shall try to log in to my backend and fail with access denied.

This is the `conf.js`:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  baseUrl:'http://127.0.0.1:4200',
  specs: ['mytest.spec.js'],
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
}
```

The webdriver was started with `webdriver-manager start`. The app loads fine and the test fills out the Auth0 popup as shown below. It then clicks the submit button. However, this leads to the error message below being shown instead of the login happening. If I understand correctly, Auth0 can't reach the auth server (which is not the issue when logging in manually).

The version of auth0 lock is 10.0.

[image: Auth0 can't reach its server]

Through `browser.pause()` I could verify that other non-localhost addresses like stackoverflow.com are accessible.

Any idea where this might come from and how to solve it?

**Update:**

In the developer console the following message is displayed.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://MYDOMAIN.eu.auth0.com/usernamepassword/login. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Can you inspect if there was an error thrown by the Lock (also which version of lock is this for?)

Comment: Updated the question accordingly and found the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the local url `http://127.0.0.1:4200` was not listed in the **auth0 dashboard under Allowed Origins (CORS)**, only `http://localhost:4200` which I used for testing manually.

The issue was resolved by adding `http://127.0.0.1:4200` to Allowed Origins (CORS) and adding the appropriate callback URLs to Allowed Callback URLs.